# Sometimes my phone will not send text messages

Tags: sms

Has anyone else had this issue? It all started after the GDR3 update I think. Now I am on the latesting Windows Phone 8.1 preview update that came out yesterday (May 14, 2014).

I haven't experienced the issue *yet* because it's only been a day, but historically the issue pops up when the phone's been on for a day or so.

What happens is I try to reply or send a SMS and it says "Failed to send" and the icon for Messages becomes a sad face. The only way to reliably fix it is by restarting the phone.

**Update (7/24/2014)**: Still receive issue even with latest Windows Dev 8.1 preview. OS 8.10.12397.895

Comment: I've only ever seen this when out of signal range - are you able to still make and receive calls when it happens?

Comment: I can receive texts but I haven't tried making calls. I can also use my data connection (off of Wi-Fi) during this state.

Comment: I use to have similar problems. But I didn't mind that much because I use Whatsapp more than SMS. Using Lumia 920.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem on HTC 8x windows 8.1. Temporary fix manually enter the recipient number instead of selecting it from contacts and don't reply to any message write new message every time by entering recipient number manually